# unit testing a python function which invokes a vim subprocess

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've written a function which opens a vim editor with the given filename when called.. How can I do the unittest of these types of operations....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To unit test something like this you must mock/stub out your dependencies.  In this case lets say you are launching vim by calling os.system("vim").

In your unit test you can stub out that function call doing something like:

```
def launchVim():
    os.system("vim")

def testThatVimIsLaunched():
    try:
        realSystem = os.system
        called = []
        def stubSystem(command):
            if command == "vim":
                called.append(True)
        os.system = stubSystem

        launchVim() # function under test

        assert(called == [True])
    finally:
        os.system = realSystem
```

For more details on mocking and stubbing take a look at [this article](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/mocking.shtml)

Update: I added the try/finally to restore the original system function as suggested by Dave Kirby

Comment: If you do this make sure you wrap the call in a try: finally: block or use setUp & tearDown to restore the original os.system afterwards.  Otherwise you will eventually write a test in an unrelated part of your test suite that tries to call the real os.system and be scratching your head wondering why it doesn't work.

Comment: Monkey-patching this way is rather tricky. If the code-to-be-mocked has gotten hold of a reference to os.system before you patch it, the patching won't have the desired effect.

Also, this is precisely what the (by now builtin) mock package does, so use that in stead :)

But my solution below describes a way to test code without the need for any patching at all

Answer (score 5):

This is no longer unittesting but integration testing. Why do you need to launch vim? Usually, you would 'mock' this, simulate the process spawning and depend on the fact that python's subprocess module is well tested.

To accomplish this in your code, you can, for example, subclass the class that implements your functionality and override the method that's responsible for spawning. Then test this subclass. I.e.

```
class VimSpawner(object): # your actual code, to be tested
    ...
    def spawn(self):
        ... do subprocess magic

    def other_logic(self):
        ...
        self.spawn()

class TestableVimSpawner(VimSpawner):
    def spawn(self):
        ... mock the spawning
        self.ididit = True

class Test(..):
    def test_spawning(self):
        t = TestableVimSpawner()
        t.other_logic()
        self.failUnless(t.ididit)
```

Comment: What's `iditit`?

Comment: It's a typo :-)

Comment: Still not sure what it stands for?

Comment: `self.i_did_it`